# Why include module affeacting all my instance object?

Tags: ruby

This has been puzzling me:

```rb
class Entry
end

module A
  def test
    print "A"
  end
end

class Entry
  include A
end

i = Entry.new
i.test    # --> print 'A', expected
p i.class.ancestors # --> [Entry, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

module B
  def test
    print "B"
  end
end

class Entry
  include B
end

ii = Entry.new
ii.test   # --> print 'B', expected
p ii.class.ancestors   # --> [Entry, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

i.test    # --> print 'B', now this is unexpected!
p i.class.ancestors    # --> [Entry, B, A, Object, kernel, BasicObject] --> WHY?
```

It seems include is changing all instance internal state too. Is there any reason it behave that way?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to extend different instances of the same class with different modules you can do so using `i.extend(A)` and `ii.extend(B)` this results in `i.test #=> A` and `ii.test #=> B` in this scenario there would be no need to have `Entry` include any module (unless you want to set a default module). You can then view the hierarchy using `i.singleton_class.ancestors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a pretty expected behaviour. In ruby, pretty much everything is a reference. `object.class` is a reference to an instance of Class class, and instances of Class are fully mutable.

Your `i` object holds a reference to `Entry` class, so does `ii`. When you do `Entry.include B` you modify the existing `Entry` class which will affect all the object that holds any reference to it. It is conceptually similar to:

```
class A
  def initialize(str)
    @str = str # holding reference to string object
  end

  attr_reader :str
end

string = 'hello'

a = A.new(string)
a.str #=> "hello"

string << " there" # modifying the string object

a.str #=> "hello there"

a.str.object_id == string.object_id #=> true
```

Now imagine how difficult it would be to work with a code where two instances of the same class would have different behaviour.

If you want some instances to have slightly different behaviour, you need to either use subclasses

```
class BEntry < Entry
  include B
end

Entry.new.test #=> 'A'
BEntry.new.test #=> 'B'
```

or you can make use of singleton classes of specific objects (warning - this can make the code a bit less maintainable)

```
a = Entry.new
b = Entry.new

b.extend(B)

a.test #=> 'A'
b.test #=> 'B'
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that probably I didn't research the Ruby internal that much. I'm thinking to use the include to create a plugin system, whereby different implementation of a class  is included at runtime according to needs. If it is a reference, seems this approach won't work then. It seems your singleton classes way of extending it can provide this but hmm, being singleton, yeah it might be a bit more work to maintain it. Any experience in creating something like that?